# Show that $a^{\log_a n}=n$

Tags: logarithms

Prove that $$a^{\log_a n}=n$$
I read it in a book that it is the 7th law of logarithms. But I don't understand how it actually works.

Comment: You take on both sides the log with base $a$.

Comment: How do you define $\log_a$?

Comment: $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$ when ...

Comment: If you are ok, you can accept the answer and set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: How is it done, setting as solved??

Comment: @Sri take a look here, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's what $\log_ax$ *means*: it's a number such that $a^{\log_ax}=x$.

Answer (score 1):

It is the **definition of logarithm**: $x=\log_an$ is indeed that value such that $a^x=n$

Answer (score 1):

People often tend to memorize too many formulas for the logarithms, and get confused.

You need only to focus on two of them, the others can be derived from these:

- $\log_a(x)=\dfrac{\ln(x)}{\ln(a)}$
- $\large{x^y=e^{y\ln(x)}}$

Thus $\quad\Large{a^{\log_a(n)}=e^{\ln(a)\log_a(n)}=e^{\ln(a)\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(a)}}=e^{\ln(n)}=n}$

Comment: You mean this $e^{(\ln a) (\log_a n)}$ right?

Comment: yes, $\exp(x)$ or $e^x$ are different writings for the same thing, I've chosen the flat writing because it is more readable on MSE for complicated expressions. [ else it ends up written very small... ]

Comment: I have edited it and used the `\Large` tag instead since you seem more comfortable with this presentation.

Answer (score 0):

taking the logarithm on both sides we get
$$\log_a  n\ln(a)=\ln(n)$$ since $a\neq 1$ then we have
$$\log_a n=\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(a)}=\log_a n$$

Answer (score 0):

$log_a\ n$ is the number we have to raise $a$ to to get $n$. If we raise $a$ to the number we have to raise $a$ to to get $n$, we get $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Take log with base $a$ both sides. 
$$(log_an)(log_aa)=log_an$$
$$log_an=log_an$$

Hence $LHS=RHS$ and hence proved